# Django: Channels and Web Socket, how to make group chats exclusive

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

Eg i have a chat application,

however, i realised that  for my application, as long as you have the link to the chat, you can enter. how do I prevent that, and make it such that only members of the group chat can access the chat. Something like password protected the url to the chat, or perhaps something like whatsapp. Does anyone have any suggestion and reference material as to how I should build this and implement the function? Thank you!

Comment: aka do yall recommend i do password protected urls, which i dont even know how to start from, or something like whatsapp for the website. Any prebuilt ones already or reference material? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am in the exact same condition as you.What I am thinking of doing
is

Store `group_url` and the respective `user_ids` (which we get from django's authentication) in a table(with two columns `group_url` and `allowed_user_ids`) or in `Redis`.
Then when a client connects to a channel,say `chat/1234` (where 1234 is the `group_url`),we get the id of that user using `self.scope['user'].id` and check them in the table.
If the `user_id`  is in the respected `group_url`,we accept the connection.Else reject the connection. I am new to this too.Suggest me if you find a better approach

Comment: ok! Please accept my answer if you liked it!

Comment: Hi man, I understand what you mean but I'm not sure how you can put it into code, as such, i've been stuck with this for the past 4 days as I'm not sure how i can continue. Would you mind showing how the code should be like? @TheGuardener If you dont mind you can do it through email if easier ;) talkingsagesincorporation@gmail.com

Comment: Hey your mail doesn't exist.

Comment: Bro try vookseducation@gmail.com instead thank you man! @TheGuardener

Comment: cause I'm currently working on a social networking platform and really require chat functionality but to be honest i dont even know how to start. I know how to build chat rooms but idk how to link a blogpost to a chatroom etc

Comment: @joowon Sent the mail.Pls check.

Comment: hey bro @TheGuardener yes your email is well-received. i also replied your email. thank you!